# Powershell Script to Compare two folders data after DFS sync

Tags: powershell

Looking for PowerShell script to compare two folders (sitting on different servers) with file name & last modified date & if file does not exist or last modified date is different then export the result in CSV with file name, last modified date & directory location.

For Example, Folder A from Server 1, syncing via DFS with Server 2. Need to run script to compare folder A (server 1) with synced folder on Server 2 to make sure sync is up to date & if any file is missing or not synced (means server 2 does not have up to date file) the result will export in CSV and upon completion of script email with that CSV should to admin.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
$ShareLocalPath = '\\Server1\FolderA'
$ShareFolderLocal = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $ShareLocalPath

$ShareCloudPath = '\\Server2\FolderA'
$ShareFolderCloud = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $ShareCloudPath

Compare-Object $ShareFolderLocal $ShareFolderCloud -Property Name, LastWriteTime,
Directory | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} |
Export-csv "C:\Reports\ShareFolder-MissingFiles.csv"
```

In the `Compare-Object` without directory property it shows correct output BUT then
directory information does not export in csv.
And if I use directory property then directory information get exported but the output shows all the files/folders instead of just showing file/folders that are missing or not synced(as per `lastWriteTime` check).

Comment: Hello, I don't mind helping but, not without seeing what you've tried so far. This isn't a request a script site.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response. attached code with the post as image since comment section has character's limit. Thanks.

Comment: You should paste the code into the question.  If anyone wants to take the code aside to test or workshop in order to help you, I don't think we want to transcribe first from an image.

Comment: actually fixed the if statement, let me paste the code. thx

Comment: You didn't include the `If(){}` Also be aware you can format as code using the "{}" on the tool bar or ctrl + k shortcut keys.  To format code inline surround with back-ticks.

Comment: Property `Directory` (you probably want to use `DirectoryName`) does not exist on DirectoryInfo objects, only on FieInfo objects.

Answer (score 0):

You've since edited the question, but there were a few issues. First of all I think you are often using `Write-Output` when you actually mean `Write-Host` `Write-Output` writes objects to the pipeline, in this case because there's nothing after it, it will end up writing to the screen (`Out-Default`) however, this distinction is likely to cause you problems in the future.

The second issue is you have a collection of objects and you're using the `-Like` to compare to a string.  This will sometimes work because of operator behavior, but considering you already filtered on `-match "<="` it's unnecessary, you can simply use `If( $file_data ){...}`. Also, `-eq "<="` is more explicit/better in this case.

Thirdly, `<=` indicates something is in the reference collection that's not in the difference collection.  How does that indicate something is in sync?

4th You are using `Get-Content` to look at CSV data.  I'm not sure why exporting to CSV is even needed, what you're doing can be accomplished without that intermediate step.

Here's one approach:

```
$ShareLocalPath = '\\Server1\FolderA'
$ShareFolderLocal = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $ShareLocalPath

$ShareCloudPath = '\\Server2\FolderA'
$ShareFolderCloud = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path $ShareCloudPath

$File_Data = Compare-Object $ShareFolderLocal $ShareFolderCloud -Property Name, LastWriteTime, Directory

If( $FileData.SideIndicator -contains "<=") {
    Write-Host "Your message..."
}
Else {
    Write-Host "A different message..."
}
```

**Update To Address Comment:**

Of course we could work out code patterns that report on files that are either missing or different in the destination.  I'd have to workshop that a bit, and without doing so I cannot say to what level of even if I'd included `Compare-Object`. Moreover this somewhat depends on what you want in the report.

However, a cool trick that can be used to sides-step the coding need is RoboCopy.  I'm sure you're not using it to actually do the synchronization, but the `/l` (for list) parameter can be used in combination with a whole bunch of logging options to get a list of files that are different in the destination.

```
$DiffFiles = 
Robocopy.exe $ShareLocalPath $ShareCloudPath /l /e /njh /np /njs /ndl /ns /nc | 
Where-Object { ![String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_) }

$DiffFiles = $DiffFiles.Trim()
$DiffFiles
```

Now this includes files that are newer in the destination than they are in the source.  It will also include files in the destination that aren't in the source, coined "Extras" in RoboCopy and some other Robocopy classes. Effectively, this considers the source to be authoritative and thus will report anything different about the files in the destination.

You can add, `/xn /xx`, there's also `/xc` to exclude changed.  You can take a look at the help file `Robocopy /?` for the full list of exclusion parameters.

The full list of RoboCopy file is noted in [this blog article](https://gcd.w3.uvm.edu/2015/04/robocopy-file-classes/) it's oddly not part of the help file.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Write-Output was only to see the result while i am testing it that what object is actually getting it will not be a part of final code & if statement was resolved as well thats why i edited my post with the part that is not working correctly. Exporting to CSV only if file/folder missing or not upto date on server 2, so that CSV can be emailed to the admin with file name, lastwritetime & directory info of files/folders needs attention. What is understood with "<=" that compare-object compare the source folder with destination folder and point out discrepant data with <=

Comment: is there a better way to compare two folders on the basis of
Name = so we know if any file/folder is missing in the synced folder
LastWriteTime = so we know if any file/folder has not synced yet (meaning source folder was updated today the real time continuous sync update the sync folder as well but in case if sync if broken then synced folder will still have old LastWriteTime on that file/folder)

& then only export the discrepant data in csv along with  name , LastWriteTime & Directory column and email to admin. With Directory column admin know where data is located that needs attention.

Comment: right, its helpful with robocopy but we are not using robocopy we are syncing through DFS.

Comment: Yeah that's fine. The demo isn't using RoboCopy to do the sync and or copy, just the reporting. As discussed `/L` and the other logging options get you there.  Like I said, you can do it purely in PowerShell, but you'll have to develop it. Getting clever with Robocopy is more expedient.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit unconventional, but you can utilize Robocopy for this and from the log create a `Compare-Object` lookalike output:

```
$ShareLocalPath = '\\Server1\FolderA'
$ShareCloudPath = '\\Server2\FolderA'

$null = & robocopy.exe $ShareLocalPath $ShareCloudPath /e /l /ns /njs /njh /fp /ts /log:C:\Reports\diff.txt

$result = switch -Regex -File 'C:\Reports\diff.txt' {
    '^\s*New File\s+(\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\s+(.*)' {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Name          = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($matches[2])
            LastWriteTime = ([datetime]$matches[1]).ToLocalTime()
            Directory     = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($matches[2])
            Type          = 'File'
            SideIndicator = '<='
        }
    }
    '^\s*New Dir\s+(.*)' {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Name          = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($matches[1].TrimEnd("\"))
            LastWriteTime = $null  # unfortunately no timestamp for directories..
            Directory     = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($matches[1].TrimEnd("\"))
            Type          = 'Directory'
            SideIndicator = '<='
        }       
    }
}
# remove the robocopy log
Remove-Item -Path 'C:\Reports\diff.txt'

# save the results as Compare-Object lookalike CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\diff.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Comment: really helpful, thank you so much. will run both ways to see which is less resource intensive. But really appreciate your help. Thank you.